# WebBrowser Control disable mouse clicks

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to show a YouTube video inside a WebBrowser control, but I want to disable all user interactions (no mouse clicks no keyboard events...).

I am catching all control's preview, mouse and keyboard events and furthermore I put some handlers to the loaded HTML document, but without any success:

```
 void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted( object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e )
 {
     if(webBrowser1.Document != null) {
         var doc = webBrowser1.Document;
         
         doc.Body.Style = "overflow:hidden";
         doc.Click      += htmlDoc_Click;
         doc.MouseDown  += htmlDoc_MouseDown;
         doc.MouseMove  += htmlDoc_MouseMove;
             
         webBrowser1.Document.Body.Click     += new HtmlElementEventHandler(htmlDoc_Click);
         webBrowser1.Document.Body.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_MouseDown);
         webBrowser1.Document.Body.MouseUp   += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_MouseMove);
         webBrowser1.Document.Body.MouseUp   += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_MouseUp);
         
         
         HtmlElement head = doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
         HtmlElement mscript = doc.CreateElement("script");
         IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)mscript.DomElement;
         element.text = "function handleMouseEvent(e) { "
                      + "var evt = (e==null ? event:e); "
                      + "return true; } "
                      + "document.onmousedown = handleMouseEvent; "
                      + "document.onmouseup   = handleMouseEvent; "
                      + "document.onclick     = handleMouseEvent; ";
         head.AppendChild(mscript);
     }
 }
```

Also it would be fine to overlay a transparent Control "in front of" the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Bind to the mouse and key events and set `e.Handled = True;` as well as `e.SuppressKeyPress = True` on the key down events.

Comment: @Jaxi: problem is that no event get triggered for youtube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a custom control derived from a standard WinForms Panel, modified to be completely transparent but "solid" (receives the Mouse events).

The transparency is achieved using [CreateParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.createparams?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) adding an `ExStyle = WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`;

Also, [Control.SetStyle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetStyle);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) method is used to modify the control behaviour, adding these [ControlStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2):

**`ControlStyles.Opaque`** prevents the painting of the control `BackGround`, so it's not managed by the System.
**`ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor`** allows the control to accept Alpha values for it's background color.
**`ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw`**  causes the redrawing of the control when it's resized.

The Custom Control is initialized passing a reference of the control it has to *overlay*. It then resizes itself to the size of this referenced control, excluding the ScrollBars from this measure, so they can be used.

---

To set it to work, create a reference to the `OverlayPanel` class and call the helper method `CreateOverlay(Control control)`:

```
private OverlayPanel overlayPanel;

private void CreateOverlay(Control control)
{
    overlayPanel = new OverlayPanel(this.webBrowser1);
    Controls.Add(overlayPanel);
    overlayPanel.BringToFront();
}
```

The `OverlayPanel` class code can be inserted in a Form or in a class file of its own.
 It should be created when all controls in a Form already have their dimensions set: in the `Form.Shown()` event or any other time when the parent form is visible. The `Form.Load()` event might also well work most of the time, anyway.

As a note, this `OverlayPanel` doesn't have a `Resize` method at this moment, which is required if the overlayed control is resized at some point. But it's quite a simple implementation, should it be needed.

```
private class OverlayPanel : Panel
{
    internal int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
    public OverlayPanel(Control RefControl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Size = new Size(RefControl.Size.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth,
                             RefControl.Size.Height - SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight);
        this.Location = RefControl.Location;
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque | 
                      ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                      ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);
        this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams parameters = base.CreateParams;
            parameters.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return parameters;
        }
    }
}
```