# DataGridView Opacity

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is there a way to change the opacity of a `DataGridView`?

I am looking for a visual for when a grid is disabled.  Any thoughts?  I cannot find a property and was wondering if anyone else has tried to do this before. Any ideas?

Comment: No support for opacity.  Set its Enabled property to False.  Faking a dimmed grid is possible by putting a Panel on top whose Parent is the grid control and BackColor is partially transparent (say Color.FromArgb(25, Color.Black)).  That however doesn't stop the user from tabbing into the grid.

Comment: ...unless you also set `[DataGridView].TabStop = false`. This one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434828/7444103) is ~the overlay Panel Hans Passant is referring to. It's a Panel that supports transparency/translucency. It's used in that question to overlay a WebBrowser control (c# code).

Answer (score 0):

Gridview is actually rendered as table.
so 
use css

```
     /*replace GridView1 with <%:Gridview1.CliendID%> in case your gridview is within master page*/
     #GridView1 tr td{ opacity: 0.5;} 
     #GridView1 tr th{ opacity: 0.5;}
```

Comment: Not a GridView, it's a DataGridView (WinForms - desktop application, quite unrelated).